# Too few arguments to function Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::import(), 1 passed and at least 2 expected

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to Import Excel Data in Laravel and Insert into Database. I am using maatwebsite/excel version 3 composer package and laravel version 5.8

**Error screenshot:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESL7n.jpg

**Blade file: import.blade.php**

```
           <form action="{{ url('/import-excel/import') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="importFile">Select Import File</label>
                    <input type="file" name="select_file" class="form-controll">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-success" value="Import File">
            </form>
```

**Controller file: ImportExcelController.php**

```
public function import(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'select_file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('select_file')->getRealPath();

    $data = Excel::import($path)->get();

    if($data->count() > 0){
        foreach($data->toArray() as $key => $value){
            foreach($value as $row){
                $insert_data[] = array(
                    'CustomerName'  => $row['customer_name'],
                    'Gender'        => $row['gender'],
                    'Address'       => $row['address'],
                    'City'          => $row['city'],
                    'PostalCode'    => $row['postal_code'],
                    'Country'       => $row['country'],
                );
            }
        }
        if(!empty($insert_data)){
            DB::table('tbl_customer')->inset($insert_data);
        }
    }
    return back()->with('success', 'Import data successfully!');
}
```

I have checked excel.php file are exits in config folder. provider and aliases added.

**route**

```
Route::get('/import-excel', 'ImportExcelController@index');
Route::post('/import-excel/import',  'ImportExcelController@import');
```

how to solve this please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the method signature for the import method:

```
public function import($import, $filePath, string $disk = null, string $readerType = null);
```

Which means that the path is a second parameter, but you are missing the first one.

The first one should be an `import` class, you create one like this as an example

```
php artisan make:import UsersImport --model=User
```

Then to use it:

```
Excel::import(new UsersImport, $path);
```

You will need to let know the library how to map each row from the file into an object for your usage.

-- EDIT

So I would create a model, but you can do the same like this:

```
class CustomersImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        $data = [];

        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            $data[] = array(
                    'CustomerName'  => $row[0],
                    'Gender'        => $row[1],
                    'Address'       => $row[2],
                    'City'          => $row[3],
                    'PostalCode'    => $row[4],
                    'Country'       => $row[5],
                );
        }

        DB::table('tbl_customer')->insert($data);
    }
}
```

So something like this, but debug what does the `rows` contains and make sure when you iterate you get the correct key to the correct column in your database.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I am not clear artisan:php artisan make:import UsersImport --model=User
here User is the model right?

Comment: Here is the documentation for it: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html

Comment: @RashedJhony that's just an example, you should use the model for your case. What type of data are you importing.

Comment: right now i am not using any model. and excel data importing

Comment: @RashedJhony take a look at my edit, it might help you a bit. So generate an import without the model, and reuse the code from above

Comment: Thank but I got this error: Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::get()

Comment: Yes, you don't need the `get()` at the end, just this `Excel::import(new UsersImport, $path);` And the data will be already imported, so your code in the controller where you iterate over the data is not needed anymore.

Comment: now I faced this issue: Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::count()

Comment: You should show code @RashedJhony I don't know what you are trying to do. Or please go through the documentation https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/ it is so well written and easy to use.

Comment: Many Thanks @nakov 
solved this issue. can you help me like, if you want to insert same excel data multiple table then how to do this please?

Comment: @RashedJhony well create your models, and create the relationships, then it will be much easier to create the data and make the associations. But you will need the power of eloquent for that a bit more. Try it yourself, and if you get stuck at some point, open a question on StackOverflow, I am sure someone will help you out.

Comment: Thanks @nakov I can now insert excel data into my multiple tables. But can you please tell me, How can I do, Table A primary id (auto increment id) save to Table B as a foreign id in user_id column?

Comment: @RashedJhony, `$tableA = TableA::create([]);` then `TableB::create(['table_a' => $tableA->id]);` or even better if you have relationship set up: `$tableA->tableB()->create([]);`.

Comment: @RashedJhony can you share the solution please? I am also stuck at same code from hours and not able to solve it. Thanks